# JsViews not removing the script tags after updating change with observable api on array

Tags: javascript, arrays, observable, jsviews

I have been working with JsViews recently. But i been getting issue with $.observable(array).refresh()

Lets just say if i have a array of objects

```
countries = [
  {country : 'India'}, 
  {country : 'USA'},
  {country : 'Africa'}
]
```

When i'm using a template to loop through each element in the array it renders the content to my requirement but when i look at the HTML structure it shows like this.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="jsv#1"></script>
    <div class="country">India</div>
    <script type="jsv/1"></script>
    <script type="jsv#2"></script>
    <div class="country">USA</div>
    <script type="jsv/2"></script>
    <script type="jsv#3"></script>
    <div class="country">Africa</div>
    <script type="jsv/3"></script>
  </body>
<html>
```

But when i get a new element in the array and push it to the top. I have the following array.

```
countries = [
  {country : 'Canada'},
  {country : 'India'}, 
  {country : 'USA'},
  {country : 'Africa'}
]
```

And then i apply

```
$.observable(countries).refresh(countries);
```

What i get on html structure is :

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="jsv#1"></script>
    <script type="jsv/1"></script>
    <script type="jsv#2"></script>
    <script type="jsv/2"></script>
    <script type="jsv#3"></script>
    <script type="jsv/3"></script>
    <script type="jsv#4"></script>
    <div class="country">Canada</div>
    <script type="jsv/4"></script>
    <script type="jsv#5"></script>
    <div class="country">India</div>
    <script type="jsv/5"></script>
    <script type="jsv#6"></script>
    <div class="country">USA</div>
    <script type="jsv/6"></script>
    <script type="jsv#7"></script>
    <div class="country">Africa</div>
    <script type="jsv/7"></script>
  </body>
<html>
```

Here the tags 'jsv#1', 'jsv#2', 'jsv#3' and their respective closing tags are not being removed.

I found this issue with JsViews V1.0 released in 2012.

Is this the correct behaviour or should i go with different approach of inserting elements.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the correct behavior.

V1.0 has not been released so I'm not clear what version you are using.

Can you switch to the latest version and try again: http://www.jsviews.com/#download.

You should not set countries to the new array, then call `refresh()` on the new array. Rather you should do:

```
var countries = [
  {country : 'India'}, 
  {country : 'USA'},
  {country : 'Africa'}
];

tmpl.link("#result", countries);

$.observable(countries).refresh([
  {country : 'Canada'},
  {country : 'India'}, 
  {country : 'USA'},
  {country : 'Africa'}
]);
```

See http://www.jsviews.com/#refresh.

But for inserting better to use `insert()`. See http://www.jsviews.com/#insert.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I was using v1.0PRE. That was what i could get from the file.

Comment: I am using the latest release (0.9.82) and am experiencing the same problem using both #refresh and #insert.  Was this ever resolved?

Comment: It should work correctly. You will have `<script type="jsv#1_"></script><script type="jsv#5_"></script>
  <div class="country">Canada</div>
<script type="jsv/5_"></script>...<script type="jsv#4_"></script>
  <div class="country">Africa</div>
<script type="jsv/4_"></script><script type="jsv/1_">` or similar

Comment: @BorisMoore I am curious to know the reason behind adding lots of `script` tags in DOM in between our HTML. Can you please share some thoughts or links if any ?

Comment: @agpt: JsViews data-linking means that observable changes to the bound data automatically trigger dynamic updates to the rendered HTML. To achieve this, JsViews `link()` method includes meta-data tokens in the rendered HTML, which it then uses as locators to ensure that content is updated at the correct places in the HTML.

The meta-data does not affect visual rendering in any way, and consists essentially of `data-jsv` attributes on some HTML elements, as well as some inserted script tags of type: `jsv...` when locators are needed within text content.